# .each() jquery is not working for all elements

Tags: jquery

I have multiple elements with same name:
Call now

When i apply below .each then alert only works for the first element and not for each element having: id="call-me"

What am I doing wrong in it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#call-me').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            alert("Test");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the same `id` on more than one element; it's an invalid DOM. `$("#call-me")` will only locate **one** of them, because jQuery will optimize that into a call to `getElementById`, which can only return one (usually the first, but as it's an invalid DOM, the browser could pick any).

Instead, group them in some other way, perhaps via `class`.

---

Separately: There's no reason to use `each` there. Just use `click` directly on the set you get back:

```
$(".call-me").click(function() {
    alert("Test");
});
```

If you need to know which one was clicked, `this` refers to the specific clicked element.

Example using `class`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.call-me').click(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="call-me">First</div>
<div class="call-me">Second</div>
<div class="call-me">Third</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

An `id`  should be unique.
Instead, use

`class="cal-me"`

and for the jquery

`$('.call-me').each...`

Answer (score 0):

@TJCrowder has correctly pointed out that using a class is the way to go. However, you do not need to use `.each()`, unless you want to see all the three when the page loads or in response to some other event. Here is how to do it without each:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //all you really need
    $('.call-me').on('click', function() {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
  
    /*//but if you must see the three alerts when the page loads then you do need each()
    $('.call-me').each(function() {
        alert( $(this).text() );
    });*/
});
```

```html
<div class="call-me">First</div>
<div class="call-me">Second</div>
<div class="call-me">Third</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**
To display text from the `div.hidemynumber` that's after `div.call-me` use:

```js
$('.call-me').on('click', function() {
    alert( $(this).next('.hidemynumber').text() );
});
```

```css
.hidemynumber {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="call-me">First</div> <div class="hidemynumber">1234</div> <div class="call-me">Second</div> <div class="hidemynumber">8855</div> <div class="call-me">Third</div> <div class="hidemynumber">7411</div>
```

A much better approach might be to place your number in a data attribute as follows:

```js
    $('.call-me').on( 'click', function() {
        alert( $(this).data( 'hidemynumber' ) );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="call-me" data-hidemynumber="1234">First</div>  <div class="call-me" data-hidemynumber="8855">Second</div>  <div class="call-me" data-hidemynumber="7411">Third</div>
```

Comment: Excellent help it worked but I am still stuck and might need bit more help:
There is one more div after each call-me div like below:

<div class="call-me">First</div>
<div class="hidemynumber">1234</div>

<div class="call-me">Second</div>
<div class="hidemynumber">1234</div>

<div class="call-me">Third</div>
<div class="hidemynumber">1234</div>

I want to access as:

$('.call-me').each(function() {
        //alert( $(this).text() );
       $(this).text($(".hidemynumber").text());
    });

It works but prints all possible values of hidemynumber where as i want to print of what is clicked.

Comment: I did call that out: *"Separately: There's no reason to use `each` there. Just use `click` directly on the set you get back"*

Comment: You're right. I probably replied too soon before you remove it from your demo code. @tjcrowder

Comment: I have used click now: 

    $('.call-me').on('click', function() {
        alert($('.hidemynumber').text());
    });

It still concatenates all values of hidemynumber on each call-me click where as i want to alert the value 1234 when first call-me is clicked, 8855 when second call-me is clicked and 7411 when 3rd call-me is clicked:

 <div class="call-me">First</div>
 <div class="hidemynumber">1234</div> 
 
 <div class="call-me">Second</div> 
 <div class="hidemynumber">8855</div> 
 
 <div class="call-me">Third</div> 
 <div class="hidemynumber">7411</div>

Comment: @Sam222, for that you need (if `.hidemynumber` is right after `.call-me`), `alert( $(this).next('.hidemynumber').text() )`. That way you maintain the context of the clicked element.

Comment: @PeterKA: Yeah -- I wrote it, then copied the OP's code to the demo, and...kinda forgot to remove it until like a minute before your post. :-)